# Проблема с шифрованием запроса ЭЛН ФСС .NET. Использую КриптоПро. Не могу найти пример с подписанием и шифрованием.

Tags: c#

Проблема с шифрованием запроса ЭЛН ФСС .NET. Использую КриптоПро. Не могу найти пример с подписанием и шифрованием. Подписать xml-файл получилось, а с шифрованием - проблема. Может есть готовый пример?